# There is no "Configure InfoPath Forms Services link" in General Application Settings heading

Tags: 2013, infopath

When I want to configure InfoPath Forms Services, I cannot find its link in the following path: Central Administration->General Application Settings.`enter code here` I am using SP 2013 foundation. Please tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is an Enterprise Edition feature only.

Check this feature availability charts :

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx

Comment: How can I add this feature to office 2013 trial?

Answer (score 0):

As this is enterprise Features, You need to install the SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise edition.

Their is no way to upgrade foundation to 2013 enterprise, or no way to add this feature in SharePoint Foundation.